# Android Animations do not affect layout

Tags: android, animation, layout

Animations affect only the drawing of widgets, which means after the animation is done, my FrameLayout screenMain is still at its previous location, y need set the FrameLayout in the next location.

```
screenMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                screenMain.startAnimation(translate);
                sh.startAnimation(translate);
                sg.startAnimation(translate);
                i++;
            } else {
                screenMain.startAnimation(translateb);
                sh.startAnimation(translateb);
                sg.startAnimation(translateb);
                i++;

            }

        }

    });
```

Code animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0.0"
        android:toXDelta="0.0"
        android:fromYDelta="0.0"
        android:toYDelta="180.0"
        android:duration="200"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        />
</set>
```

Code animationb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0.0" 
        android:toXDelta="0.0" 
        android:fromYDelta="180.0"
    android:toYDelta="0.0" 
        android:duration="200" 
        android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a view's position, you need to call view.setLayoutParams(). An easy way to achieve this animation effect is to first call setLayoutParams() to the end position, then invoke TranslateAnimation from the original location.

Here's more details of how to: http://www.clingmarks.com/?p=400

Comment: What is the relation between the animation and the layout of views
because of which, after the animation, the location of views is not
same as before the animation?

Comment: A translate animation does not actually change the position of the view. It changes
where it is drawn, not its position within the layout.